# How to fix https error

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ssl

This is wordpress site, and I have installed ssl certificate for some **.php** pages only, then I removed ssl certificate from server. Now the page loaded with https and its crossed out but wordpress website running normally but **.php** files not loading its through error like below.

**The requested URL /indiv/login.php was not found on this server.**

Apache Server at www.mydomain.com Port 443

Below is my current .htaccess code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /indiv/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /indiv/index.php [L]
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/indiv/ [R=301]
RewriteRule ^indiv/?$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/indiv/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Note: I cleared browser cache but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this line from your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteRule ^indiv/?$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/indiv/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Got error like this: The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

    This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.